# amazon ec2 boto returns null instances

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, boto

i am using the boto python module for polling amazon ec2 instances, however it returns null values,

i can retrieve and list images using conn.get_all_images

```
import sys
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection

conn = EC2Connection('access key','secret key')
inst = conn.get_all_instances()
for i in inst:
    print i
```

i tried it from python command line and it also has the same result

```
>>>import sys
>>>from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
>>>conn = EC2Connection('access key','secret key')
>>> instances = conn.get_all_instances()
>>> instances
[]
>>>
```

any idea what the problem could be? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was looking at the wrong region, fixed when i used the correct one..

```
regions = boto.ec2.regions(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,is_secure=False)
eu = regions[0]
conn_eu = eu.connect(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        inst = conn_eu.get_all_instances()
```